# TC Corruption of Packets Ingress

Tags: unix, terminal, tc

I’m new to tc & this may be naive question but correct me if I’m wrong

`tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem corrupt 5%`

Does above command corrupt ingress packets only ?

If Yes, does outgress corruption has support with different command to configure ?

PS: I couldn’t find relevant help online for outgress corruption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `netem` is a egress queue discipline and affects only outgoing packets, not ingress. To dive into the TC you can read the [LARTC (Linux advanced routing and traffic control)](https://lartc.org/howto/)

Other useful sources of information are `man tc` and `man tc-netem`, specially the examples sections.

Comment: Fwiw, for the reverse feature (ingress) it's also possible to use an IFB interface (which behaves as an egress interface in the ingress path) + mirred redirect action to get netem (or most other egress-only features) working on ingress, should this be needed.